# Permanently enabling volume control for audio interface that doesn't support it

Tags: macos, audio, sound-volume, soundflower

I use an audio interface (namely a Roland Edirol UA-5, but that doesn't matter) which does not support volume control. I can only control the volume with the physical volume dial on the audio interface.

Now, by combining two freewares from [RogueAmoeba](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/), Soundflower and LineIn, I am able to enable volume control on any audio interface by:

1. Selecting Soundflower as my primary audio interface
2. Routing Soundflower to my Edirol UA-5 with LineIn

Thus enabling my native volume to control my audio interface.

This is my question now: is there a native modification I could make to OSX (a flag somewhere, a special kext) that could make this process easier?